# "You and I combined" versus "you and me combined"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Which is correct, "you and I combined" or "you and me combined"? as in:

> Bob and I combined had 91 points

The "combined" confuses me.

Comment: Does the "combined" confuse you because of the compound subject "Bob and I"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the original sentence, "Bob and I combined had 91 points", *combined* isn't the main verb. You could rewrite the sentence and still maintain its meaning by saying:

> Together, Bob and I had 91 points.

The *combined* is serving more as a qualifier of the subject "Bob and I" rather than as a verb. It could be described as a [participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle), which shares characteristics of both verbs and adjectives.

So in this case, "Bob and I combined" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking of it in this way:

> When Bob and I were combined, we had 91 points.

I hope that makes it clearer. To answer your question, "you and I combined" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said, "Bob and I had 91 points, combined."  *Combined* is used to distinguish 91 total points from "Bob and I have 91 points each." (A comment about the compound subject: *Informally*, people might say, *Bob and me* or even *Me and Bob* in that sentence. You and I is correct as a subject, you and me is correct as an object.)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, would you say?

```
Me had 91 points.
```

or

```
I had 91 points.
```

The use of `combined` is irrelavent. In this case `me` is wrong, `I` is right.

You may insert any length of description between `I` and `had` and as long as you add no other verb than `have`, `I` will always be right. No description of unity, togetherness or combination can change that.